# Unit tests fail when using Moles 0.94 and VS2012, "Hosting rules specify that the test type 'Unit Test' cannot run in the host adapter 'Moles'"

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, moles, pex

I'm trying to run some Unit Tests using Moles 0.94 and VS2012 in preparation to moving to TFS 2012.
The tests currently work fine on a TFS 2010 build server.

The first error I got was:

> The host type 'Moles' cannot be loaded for the following reason: The
>   key 'Moles' cannot be found. Make sure that the appropriate host
>   adapter is installed on the machine. Exception doesn't have a
>   stacktrace

I found that the Moles installer didn't create the correct entries in the registry, as per a comment in this post: [Test Fails Due to Moles Under 64-bit Process](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/pex/thread/176b2fc5-882e-413b-b4d5-10ea6b486e65)

I decided to update my registry, so under Visual Studio\11.0\ the host adapters are now there too. They were only there for 10.0 before.

In my test.settings file I've tried both **Force 32 bit** and **Run in 64 bit**.
I've added the following to my Assembly.cs:

> `[assembly: MolesAssemblySettings(Bitness = MolesBitness.x64)]`

I now get the following error:

> Hosting rules specify that the test type 'Unit Test' cannot run in the
>   host adapter 'Moles'. To run this test in 'Moles', change the hosting
>   rules. To use the default test host for tests that cannot be run in
>   the specified host adapter, change the test settings.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please keep in mind that in Visual Studio 2012, Moles framework has been replaced with Fakes. Here is how to migrate: http://www.hoonzis.com/fakes-is-new-test-isolation-framework/

Comment: Can Moles run though in VS2012 or does it need replacing?

Comment: Technically, it may be possible to brute-force it, but you'd have to figure out how to do it. Legally, you have to check the EULA.

Comment: Ahh I guess that's my question then, I've tried to brute force it but it doesn't seem to work. Do you know anyone who may has?

Comment: I have tried to brute force Moles on VS2012, to address questions like yours. I have not been successful. It appears there may be framework version restriction control hidden away in there. It still may be possible; I gave up trying a little too easily (a horrible thing to admit, but true). Have you seen this article? It may not resolve your issue, but is relevant: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/moles/molesdev11.aspx

Comment: FYI - In the end it was easier to replace/refactor the tests that were using it